# Sitefinity RESTful API Webservice: GET a set of data items of contenttype returns 0 items?

Tags: json, rest, web-services, sitefinity

I have a content type "bomeldungs" with 2 items in it.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbeBW.png)

I have set up a RESTful API webservice.
With the GET "API URL HERE" i must get all 2 items in a json format. It must look like this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHvnm.png)

Calling the API URL in the Postman Application, im getting a successfull 200 OK Status, but in the JSON there are 0 items.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7afk7.png)

How can this happen?

Comment: Are you doing any filters or passing any query strings to the API? Also are you using multisite management and maybe that content is NOT on the default site? If using multisite management you will need to pass ?sf_site={{GUID of Site}} to the url to retain context.

Comment: @JonR. how do u pass the param? when I do so I get a 404. `https://<domain>/api/default/entity?sf_site=<site_guid>`

Comment: Did you replace entity with the name of your content type? You could also try passing the provider name ?sf_provider or as Steve mentioned check the permission on that service.

Answer (score 0):

Checked permissions? If you’re logged into the browser you’d see items, where you’d be anonymous in postman.